# Generics and IComparable - error CS00301

Tags: c#, .net, generics, icomparable

I've tried to develop a generic class "MinHeap(T)" implementing IComparable. It works fine when generic is "int" or another class "Code". Going further and using for T a generic class "Node(Code)"
leads to the error mentioned below.

I'm probably too new and not understanding subtle differences between IComparable and IComparable(T). Does someone have an idea ?
Thanks in advance for your help,
LJ

```
public class MinHeap<T> where T : IComparable
{
...
}
public class Node<T> where T : IComparable
{
    T data
...
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Node<T> otherNode = obj as Node<T>;
        return this.data.CompareTo(otherNode.data);
    }
...
}
public class Code : IComparable
{
    public int freq;
...
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Code otherCode = obj as Code;
        return this.freq.CompareTo(otherCode.freq);
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MinHeap<int> hInt = new MaxHeap<int>(heapSeed); // works fine
    MinHeap<Code> hCode = new MinHeap<Code>(codeList); // works fine
...
    Node<Code>[] nodeCodeList = new Node<Code>[freqList.Length]; // ok        
    MinHeap<Node<Code>> h = new MinHeap<Node<Code>>(nodeCodeList); // Error
...
}
```

Error message:

> Error  2   The type 'Algorithms.Node(Algorithms.Code)' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Algorithms.MinHeap(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Algorithms.Node(Algorithms.Code)' to 'System.IComparable'.

Comment: `T` should not only be comparable, `Node<T>` should be too.

Comment: The followoing should work: `public class Node<T> : IComparable where T : IComparable` . Same for MinHeap. @Aphelion has the explanation.

Comment: Works now fine - the was no need to do the same for MinHeap<T> - Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class  `Node<T>` does not implement `IComparable`. It just haves a constraint for the type of `T`.

It looks like you've tried to implement the [decorator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp) pattern. Implement the interface as well and then map the methods to the decorated object.

Comment: MinHeap<T> doesn't have to implement IComparable.

Comment: @empi Thank you!  I've modified the answer.

Comment: Code modified as suggested @leppie 
Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off defining your generic class so that it doesn't *require* the type to implement `IComparable<T>`. That's how the .NET generic classes are implemented. They will use the default comparison for the type, or use the `IComparer<T>` that you pass in. For example, `SortedList` has these constructors (among others):

```
SortedList<TKey, TValue>(); // uses default comparer for TKey
SortedList<TKey, TValue>(IComparer<T> comparer); // uses supplied comparer
```

It's easy enough to implement:

```
public class MinHeap<T>
{
    private IComparer<T> _comparer;

    public MinHeap<T>(IComparer<T> comp)
    {
        _comparer = comp;
    }

    public MinHeap<T>()
        : this(Comparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }
}
```

That way, your clients can use `MinHeap<T>` to hold instances of classes that do not implement `IComparable<T>`.

When you do your comparisons, you call `_comparer.Compare(item1, item2)`

On another note, there's no particular need for your heap to require a node. You can implement a binary heap in an array. See, for example, [A Generic BinaryHeap Class](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=789).

Answer (score 1):

You should implement IComparable interface within Node class, like this:

```
  public class Node<T>: IComparable<Node<T>> // <- IComparable<Node<T>> implemented  
    where T: IComparable  {

    T data;

    ...

    #region IComparable<Node<T>> Members

    // interface implementation, not just a method
    public int CompareTo(Node<T> other) {
      // Let us be accurate with possible nulls:  
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, other))
        return 1; // <- or -1 if you think it's right
      else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(data, other.data))   
        return 0;
      else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, data))   
        return -1; // <- or 1 if you think it's right

      return data.CompareTo(other.data);
    }

    #endregion IComparable<Node<T>> Members
  }
```

depending on algorithm of min heap, you may have to implement IComparable> in MinHeap class as well

Comment: I think you need to do the `ReferenceEquals(data, other.data)` first. Otherwise, it will *always* return -1 if `other.data == null`, even if `this.data == null`.

Comment: Sorry, but ReferenceEquals(data, other.data) can't be the first. What if other is null? In this case other.data will throw an exception.